# Complex 3-D Euclidean space - inner product

Tags: euclidean-geometry, inner-products, complex-geometry

**1st question:** Lets say we have a 3-D complex euclidean space. How do we geometrically draw this space? if 3-D real Euclidean space is represented by these base vectors:

[image]

**2nd question:**
Is there a **proof** that for the scalar product in a 3-D complex Euclidean space and written in Dirac notation it holds this:

$$\langle A | B\rangle = {A_x}^*B_x + {A_y}^*B_y + {A_z}^* B_z $$

where ${A_x}^*$ is a conjugate of $A_x$. This equation can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Inner_products_and_bras).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex number can be represented by a pair of real numbers with some additional rules for multiplication. Therefore,  a complex space of dimension $n$ can be seen as a real space of dimension $2n$, with some additional structure of multiplication (which we may ignore when it's not needed: for example, when drawing).

- It's easy to draw a 1-dimensional complex space, because it is also a 2-dimensional real space, a plane.
- It's next to impossible to accurately draw a 2-dimensional complex space, because it is also a 4-dimensional real space, and humans are not good at visualizing or drawing 4 dimensions.
- Since the 3-dimensional complex space is also  a 6-dimensional real space, it is much too large for us to draw.

So, people resort to surrogates, such as Reinhardt diagrams ([seen here](https://planetmath.org/hartogstriangle)), or  drawing slices of $\mathbb C^n$. These don't represent the space, just some aspects of it.

---

For the second question: before proving something about a mathematical object, one must *define* it. How do you define the scalar product on $\mathbb C^3$? Two definitions are I know are:  $\langle a,b\rangle=\sum \bar a_j b_j$ and $\langle a,b\rangle=\sum a_j \bar b_j$. These are not the same; some people prefer the first and others prefer the second. There's no accounting for taste.

Comment: There are no diagrams anymore in the PlanetMath link (I can't find a backup of the .eps file anywhere.) Essentially,a Reinhardt diagram is a drawing of a Reinhardt domain, which is a set that only depends on $|z|$ and $|w|$ (hence allowing easy 2D illustration.) There are further examples in this expository paper: Range, R. Michael
Complex analysis: a brief tour into higher dimensions. Am. Math. Mon. 110, No. 2, 89-108 (2003). ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647769), [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=complex+analysis+brief+tour+ai%3Arange.r-michael))